# Querying a set of Keys on firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to retrieve children on a specific node on my Firebase database.
However I don't want to pull down all of them, I'm only interested in a specific set for which I have the keys. 
I know I can accomplish this by just retrieving all of the children and check for their KEYs when they come back, but I expect this particular node children to grow quite large, and doing this would be extremely inefficient.

I could also explicitly aim each children like this:

```
firebase.child(PARENT_NODE).child("objectId1").addValueEventListener(this);
firebase.child(PARENT_NODE).child("objectId2").addValueEventListener(this);
firebase.child(PARENT_NODE).child("objectId3").addValueEventListener(this);
```

But this doesnt feel "right", somehow. I would have to unsubscribe from three or more connections, I can see this getting messy quickly.
Is there a way to do something like:

```
firebase.child(PARENT_NODE).children(new String[] {"objectId1", "objectId2", "objectId3"}).addValueEventListener(this);
```

Thanks

Comment: firebase.child(PARENT_NODE).orderByKey().startAt(YOUR_START).endAt(YOUR_END).addValueEventListener(this);

Comment: Unfortunately, my keys dont follow any specific order

Comment: Loading multiple items in Firebase is a lot faster than you may expect. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786